# how to find a certain row index in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how can i find the index number of a row (tr) with a certain id value in a table with jquery?
i mean i want to know for example the row with id="2" is where in a table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) without any parameters to get an element's position amongst siblings, like this:

```
var i = $("#2").index();
```

Note though that `2` isn't a valid ID in HTML4, it should be prefixed with something, since IDs can't *start* with numbers.  Also there's the much faster/simpler `.rowIndex` DOM property way:

```
var i = document.getElementById("2").rowIndex;
```

Or, the combination:

```
var i = $("#2")[0].rowIndex;
```

Comment: thank you Nick.it is exactly what i need  and Happy Wedding ! ;)